# sql alchemy column value dependent on other table

Tags: sqlalchemy

If there's a table with a column that I want to get the number of occurrences of the columns 'id' in another tables column?

So if there was a table 'player' of every player, and a table 'goals' that listed every goal scored, is there an easy way to autoupdate the player column every time a goal they score is added to the goal table?

another example would be a 'team' and 'players' table, where the table updates the team.number_of_players every time a player is added with `player.team_name  == team.name` or something like that.

Would using JSON as a way of holding `{'username': True}` or something like that for each user be worthwhile?

Comment: There's no need to create a new column with the count an update it when an event happens. Taking the example of players and goals, you could make a `join` between the two tables and then `count` the number of goals. Take a look to documentation, [join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html), [count](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to implement you idea:

1. Easiest way: you can update your columns with update query, something like this:

   ```
       try:
           player = Player(name='New_player_name', team_id=3)
           Session.add(player)
           Session.flush()
           Session.query(Team).filter(Team.id == Player.team_id).update({Team.players_number: Team.players_number + 1})
           Session.commit()
       except SQLAlchemyError:
           Session.rollback()
           # error processing
   ```
2. You can implement sql-trigger. But an implementation is different for different DBMS. So, you can read about it in the documentation of your DBMS.
3. You can implement SQLAlchemy trigger, like this:

```
    from sqlalchemy import event

    class Team(Base):
        ...


    class Player(Base):
       ...

        @staticmethod
        def increment_players_number(mapper, connection, player):
            try:
                Session.query(Team).filter(Team.id == player.team_id)\
                         .update({Team.players_number: Team.players_number + 1})
            except SQLAlchemyError:
                Session.rollback()
                # error processing

    event.listen(Player, 'after_insert', Player.increment_players_number)
```

4. As you see, there are always two queries, because you should perform two procedures: insert and update. I think (but I'm not sure) that some DBMS can process queries like this:

```
    UPDATE table1 SET column = column + 1 WHERE id = SOMEID AND (INSERT INTO table2 values (VALUES))
```

Comment: oh, sure, you need `Session.commit()` inside `try` of `increment_players_number` method